# RESTful Event Notification mechanism to client in a non-browser system

Tags: rest, http, events, curl, lighttpd

I want to implement event notification mechanism from server (FCGI app behind lighttpd server) to client (non browser based C application). The client often POST and receive response from the server application. The client uses libcurl to do that. It doesn't maintain any persistent connection. However, I have a requirement to send events often from server to client. The client doesn't listen on any particular port. I don't want to do that explicitly. Can we design this event notification using CURL without polling from client?

I noticed there are many solutions for this scenario, when the client is a browser. My case, is a non-browser client.

Comment: If the client, can't listen on any ports, then any sort of [pub/sub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) system. must involve the client polling the server in some way. You can either do [long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) (which requires keeping a connection open), or periodic short polls. Even browsers usually use a combination of these methods.

Comment: yes, seems I should accomplish this via long-polling. thanks.